# Where does the /api directory come from in an Express application?

Tags: node.js, express

For example:

```
router.get('/api/todos', function (req, res){
    db.todos.find(function (err, data){
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

I am having a hard time understanding what '/api/todos/ actually means. I don't have a directory name either one of these in my application. What exactly is this and where is it?

Comment: That means if someone will access  the route '`http://localhost-or-your-site/api/todos`', your app will execute the corresponding function, and `res` object inside of it will **res**pond to the **req**uest.

Comment: ok i get that, but where does that route originate from? like how or where is it created.

Comment: It doesnt exist anywhere. You just created it with that line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/api/todos/` does not refer to a local file, it corresponds to a URL request. In the function you provided, if you were to add this route to an express app then visit `http://localhost/api/todos`, the server would respond with the JSON data returned from the database query you are making.

```
router.get('/api/todos', function (req, res){
```

This first line accepts all `GET` requests to `/api/todos`, and passes the `req` and `res` objects     into a callback for you to work with. See http://www.murvinlai.com/req-and-res-in-nodejs.html for an explanation of those objects.

```
db.todos.find(function (err, data){
```

Here, it is assumed that you have a `db` object which may perform database lookups based on some kind of input parameters.

```
res.json(data);
```

The `res.json` method simply sends the JSON back to the client that requested it.

See https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/understanding-express-routes for further info on routing in express.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a directory. That's a URL. Routers route URLs to resources. It could be files, it could be other URLs or most commonly it could be some javascript logic that generates the response you want (JSON, XML, HTML, PDF etc.)